# read variable excel data into variant with the same format

Tags: vba, excel, variables, data-structures

I'm currently writing a Macro for Excel. First I want to read my variable settings from row 20 from my sheet "Filter" into my variable "test":

```
' Define Last Column with a value
LastCol = Sheets("Filter").Cells(20, Sheets("Filter").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Col_Letter = Split(Cells(1, LastCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

' Read Data into variable
test = Sheets("Filter").Range("B20:" & Col_Letter & "20").Value
```

This works fine so far and I get a variant with a structure like that:

```
test
  test(1)
    test(1,1) = value1
    test(1,2) = value2
    test(1,3) = value3
    ...
```

My problem comes now: 
When I have only one value to read, the structure changes automatically to following:

```
test = value1
```

How can I change the structure to this?

```
test
  test(1)
    test(1,1) = value1
```

My problem is that with this one variable I run into various problems in my code (ubound, lbound, ...).

Comment: Your other code should check if `test` is an array before trying to loop through it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you for your inputs! R3uK has the most structured answer I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could force `test` to be an array with only one cell, if the last column is B or less :

```
' Define Last Column with a value
LastCol = Sheets("Filter").Cells(20, Sheets("Filter").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Col_Letter = Split(Cells(1, LastCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

If LastCol <= 2 Then
    ReDim test(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    test(1, 1) = Sheets("Filter").Range("B20").Value
Else
    'Read Data into variable
    test = Sheets("Filter").Range("B20:" & Col_Letter & "20").Value
End If
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the input! Works perfectly fine :) so simple and yet solved my hours of problems!

Comment: Glad I could help! ;) And it is usual to spend hours on a simple matter as we can't know all of the tricks, that's why that site is so magical/practical!

Answer (score 2):

You can check the length .. Try the following code:

```
Dim test As Variant
test = Sheets("Filter").Range("B20:" & Col_Letter & "20").Value
If Len(test) = 1 Then
        ReDim test(1, 1)
        test(1, 1) = Sheets("Filter").Range("B20:" & Col_Letter & "20").Value
End If
```

Comment: Here, it might be more practical to use `ReDim test(1 To 1, 1 To 1)`, because for your solution, `LBound(test,1)=0` and `LBound(test,2)=0` so there will be 3 empty cells (`test(0,0)`, `test(1,0)` and `test(1,1)`) in that array.